# QGIS Mapserver install and URL not working on 18.04

Tags: qgis, server

Giving QGIS Mapserver a go, the url `curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/bjw/QGIS-Training-Data-master/exercise_data/qgis-server-tutorial-data/world3.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities` only returns some binary output, not xml, nor a map. Is there an example of how this should work?

Have followed the guide: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#serve-a-project

and this older info https://www.paulshapley.com/2016/07/how-to-install-qgis-server-on-ubuntu.html  to no avail.

Comment: do you get an error? sounds like apache2 is not installed or restarted

Comment: Apache is running. It has been restarted too.

Comment: Have put it down to a bad install. Trying again.